# Display manager not working in Ubuntu 22.04 on Digital Ocean

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, ubuntu-mate, display-manager

I have running VM on Digital Ocean which runs Ubuntu 22.04, since GNOME desktop is really slow i decided to install xfce and mate but after successful installation i cannot change the display manager on the login screen, in fact I'm not seeing any option to do so either.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the display manager configuration file needs to be updated, do this to see if it is that:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

then change the value to the path of the new display manager you want to use, so for `LightDM` it will be `/usr/bin/lightdm` then reboot sudo reboot